# CSS доступность относительно контента

Tags: html, css

На css хочу сделать:

При такой структуре

```
<div class="admin-include">
    <div class="bx-context-toolbar-empty-area">
        text
    </div>
</div>
```

`admin-include` доступный, кликабельний, видимый

---

При такой:

```
<div class="admin-include">
    text
</div>
```

`admin-include` недоступный, некликабельний, невидимый, никак не повлиял на DOM

Comment: В чем суть вопроса ?

Comment: Свойства родителя не могут зависеть от потомков. Нерешаемо на css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.admin-include {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.admin-include:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: -10em;
}

.bx-context-toolbar-empty-area {
  margin-top: 10em;
  white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
AAAAAAAA

<div class="admin-include">
    <div class="bx-context-toolbar-empty-area">
        text
    </div>
</div>

BBBBBBBB

<div class="admin-include">
    text
</div>

CCCCCCCC
```

Answer (score 2):

По большему счету никак, разве что так, но очень специфично:

```css
.admin-include { font-size: 0; }

.admin-include:nth-child(1) { background-color: green; }
.admin-include:nth-child(2) { background-color: red; }

.bx-context-toolbar-empty-area { font-size: 14px; }
```

```html
<div class="admin-include">
    <div class="bx-context-toolbar-empty-area">
        text
    </div>
</div>
<div class="admin-include">
    text
</div>
```

Не `display: none;` конечно, но блока по сути не видно, большего css'ом не сделать

Comment: Я тоже нашаманил)))

Comment: @Qwertiy, ох и любишь же ты какие-то нестандартные решения xDDD

Comment: Ага))) Кстати, я его уже подправил, чтобы оно от line-height не зависело.

Comment: Сначала думал, что можно будет использовать для резиновых блоков с "расхлопыванием", но нет, а жаль =/ Все равно зависит, только теперь от margin ...

Comment: Так вроде ж можно? `white-space: nowrap;` гарантирует, что будет ровно одна строка. `10em` заведомо больше высоты этой строки. Если туда пихать элементы, можно добавить `.admin-include > * { display: none; }`.

Comment: ну вот в том, что зависит от высоты контента и проблема. Для многострочного текста не подойдет. Под задачу норм, но я хотел несколько иначе использовать.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64994/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-medvedevdev).